# What makes an electrolyte strong - solubility or dissociation?

Tags: solubility

I'm having some confusion related to the terms mentioned in the title. Suppose we have a strong electrolyte but with a very low solubility.

Therefore a given amount of it will not be able to produce lots of ions because less of it will go into solution and dissociate, so what do we call this type of electrolyte overall: a weak electrolyte as it didn't produce many ions or a strong electrolyte as whatever that did dissolve produced as many ions as it can dissociate into?

Comment: Not dissolved part does not count. If you mix 100 mL of water and 100 kg of NaCl, does it make it weak electrolyte,because majority is not dissolved ?

Comment: @Poutnik if you dissolve 100kg of NaCl in 100L of water then also it will be a strong electrolyte and solution will be fairly conducting but if you dissolve equimolar amount of electrolyte of type OP considers in question in same amount of water, it will not be a fairly conducting solution , In that case  how can you say that the considered electrolyte is strong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can an insoluble compound be a strong electrolyte](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22033/how-can-an-insoluble-compound-be-a-strong-electrolyte)

Comment: @Lllt  By evaluating molar conductivity, related to total solution concentration. Strong electrolytes have molar conductivity corresponding to ion conductivities at given concentration. Weal electrolytes have molar conductivity much lower. // The mistake is evaluation of conductivity instead of molar conductivity. By this way 0.000001 M NaCl would be weak electrolyte as well.

Comment: @Poutnik therefore we can conclude that the electrolyte of the type that OP considered in solution shall be a strong electrolyte as whatever amount of it is dissolved it will completely break into ions

Comment: @Lllt Yes, similarly as listed in the referred duplicate question.

Comment: See also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/131070/is-there-any-difference-between-getting-dissolved-and-getting-dissociated?rq=1 and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27863/can-a-strong-electrolyte-be-sparingly-soluble?rq=1&noredirect=1

Comment: @Poutnik do you have an example of substance which is strong electrolyte in one solvent and weak electrolyte in other solvent though it dissolves in both

Comment: @Lllt You should post it as the question.